# Переход с главной формы на вкладку PageControl

Tags: delphi

У меня имеется 2 формы, на одной несколько кнопок, а на второй Объект PageControl с несколькими вкладками, названия которых совпадает с названиями кнопок на первой форме. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на первой форме, осуществлялся переход на вторую форму и открывалась именно та вкладка, которая мне нужна, а не самая первая?

Пыталась осуществить это таким образом, но не получилось

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form1.hide;
  form3.TabSheet2.Show;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давненько я не брал в руки дельфи, но насколько мне помнится за активную вкладку отвечают свойства ActivePageIndex и ActivePage
Т.е. надо сделать что-то вроде

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePage := TabSheet2;
end;
```

или

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 1;
end;
```

Еще  это кажется не вызывает события смены страницы, если оно нужно - то ручками.

Comment: @Volt, я вас поняла, но так не переходит. при нажатии кнопки на 1 форме потом просто из программы выбивает

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова, ну естественно надо убедиться что мы обращаемся к элементам в доступных неймспейсах, что все имена правильно проставили. А почему вылетает - хз, в дебаггере пройтись надо посмотреть, может скажет что полезное)

Comment: @Volt, спасибо! Разобралась))))

Answer (score 2):

Допустим у нас есть 2 формы - Form1 и Form2

Что бы переключиться с 1 формы на 2 нужно на первой форме поставить кнопку и на событие on click написать следующий код (естевственно пишем после begin)

```
Form1.visible := false;
Form2.show;
```

Первая форма скрывается, а нужная вторая форма появляется, само собой таким способом можно переходить на любую форму, главное указать на какую форму вам нужно перейти.

Еще один ньюанс, форма может появиться в том месте, где вы ее конструировали, и что бы формы шли одна за одной, нужно:
В свойстве формы найти свойство position, и выбрать `poMainFormCenter` либо `poScreenCenter`.